# Radio SEDs for quasars

Tags: radio-astronomy, spectroscopy, quasars

Using data from https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/, I can get nice-looking spectral energy distributions for quasars, such as for these two:
[image]
[image]

but most of their points are in UV to IR range. I'm looking particularly for quasars with lots of radio points (i.e. frequency < 1e12 Hz), since that's the region I'm using in my research.

In the link above, you search for objects by name, but I don't know the names of any quasars with lots of points in the radio range. Are there any known like this? I only need a couple, as examples in my report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking explicitly for radio-loud quasars, I'd recommend looking at a catalog of (mainly extragalactic) radio sources, rather than a catalog of quasars, given that only a small fraction of quasars are radio-loud.

The [Third Cambridge Catalogue of Radio Sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Cambridge_Catalogue_of_Radio_Sources) ([VizieR link](http://vizier.cfa.harvard.edu/viz-bin/VizieR-3?-source=VIII/1A&-out.max=50&-out.form=HTML)) might be a nice starting point, particularly given how many objects are referred to by their 3C designation, although not all of the objects listed there are quasars - there are plenty of Seyfert galaxies and a small number of pulsars. As an example, [here's the NED entry for the quasar 3C 286](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/byname?objname=3C+286&hconst=67.8&omegam=0.308&omegav=0.692&wmap=4&corr_z=1), along with its SED:

[image: SED of quasar 3C 286]

The 3C survey was conducted at 159 MHz and then 178 MHz, so you'll certainly see lots of very low-frequency sources in there, which sounds ideal for your purposes. Again, though, this is just a starting point, and your mileage may vary if you opt for other catalogs.